# How to properly generate link to razor page that doesn't change with route parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to razor pages and obviously must be missing something, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to generate a link to a razor page that won't magically change and include optional route parameters - IF I'm on that page.

The issue I think stems from the link in question being in a nav menu that's always on the page - even when I'm on the page in question.

Specifically let's say my page is /Customer/Invoices.  I've got a link in the menu that I've tried generating via the asp-page tag helper, Url.Page, etc.  It works perfectly when I'm anywhere in the app, or even on the page in question, *as long as I don't have any route parameters*.  If I access the page with a route parameter, then that menu link magically also has it.

To recap, if I browse to .../Customer/Invoices - the link is fine even when I'm on the page.
If I browse to .../Customer/Invoices/123 - the link in the menu suddenly *also* has the 123 route parameter on the end.

I just want the static page url with no optional route parameter - regardless of whether or not I'm on the page in question with a route parameter.  I have got to be missing something...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,.net core tag helper will generate url with route parameters is by design.If you want to remove route parameters.Here are two solutions.

1.set empty route parameter in `<a>` tag.Here is a demo:

Page(Test1/Test):

```
@page "{id?}"
<a asp-page="Test" asp-route-id="1">link1</a>
<a asp-page="Test" asp-route-id="">link2</a>
```

result:
[image]

2.use href to replace `<a>` tag:

Page(Test1/Test):

```
@page "{id?}"
<a asp-page="Test" asp-route-id="1">link1</a>
<a href="/Test1/Test">link2</a>
```

result:
[image]